# Derivative of $E\left(\int_t^T S_udu|\mathcal{F}_t\right)$

Tags: derivatives, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Calculate the derivarive of $E\left(\int_t^T S_udu|\mathcal{F}_t\right)$ in function of $t$
$$\frac{d}{dt}E\left(\int_t^T S_udu|\mathcal{F}_t\right)$$
where $S_t$ is a stochastic process( I try to avoid specifying its form).

**My attempt:**
We have
$$E\left(\int_t^T S_udu|\mathcal{F}_t\right) = \int_t^T E\left(S_u|\mathcal{F}_t\right)du$$
then
$$\frac{d}{dt}E\left(\int_t^T S_udu|\mathcal{F}_t\right) = \frac{d}{dt}\left(\int_t^T E\left(S_u|\mathcal{F}_t\right)du\right) $$
But after that, I don't know how to calculate
$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\int_t^T E\left(S_u|\mathcal{F}_{\color{red}{t}}\right)du\right) $ because of the subscript in red color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think it's derivable ? Take for example $(S_t)$ being a Brownian motion. Then $$\mathbb E\left[\int_t^T S_u\,\mathrm d u\mid \mathcal F_t\right]=S_t(T-t),$$

which is not derivable.

Comment: Thank you. It's a good counter example. Besides, could you give me an idea whether we can calculate $$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\int_t^T \frac{1}{S_t}E\left(S_u|\mathcal{F}_{\color{red}{t}}\right)du\right) $$ ? The point that I want to emphasize is how we calculate the derivative on the filtration $\mathcal{F}_\color{red}t$

Comment: It's the same problem... a priori such expression is not derivable. You must find a closed form first and then see if you can derivate it or not. Here, the expression is at the end deterministic, but it will not be true in general. @NN2